# Trying to echo a button when user_id == user_id , PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, if-statement, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make a button so when the users -> user_id == the same as the products-> user_id echo a button but its not working. So only when the product has the same user_id as the session user_id , I want to echo a button with a link to another page but its not working.

This is what I tried to do:

```
<div class="cadeau_bewerken">
        <?php if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] ==  $product["user_id"]): ?>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"> Cadeau bewerken </a>
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I do see a button but its not a link and not working and I'm getting this error:

> A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED
>     Severity: Notice
>     Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>     Filename: views/details.php
>     Line number: 54

This is line number 54 in details.php:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"> Cadeau bewerken </a>
```

And yes I defined $product because on the same page I'm able to echo the name for example like this:

```
<?php echo $product['product_name']; ?>
```

Comment: Please post your modal function.

Comment: `$product` is array or object. Nothing both. In your example it's an array.

Comment: There is no model function that belongs to this code.. I'm trying to echo a button on the view page when the session user_id is the same as product user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code you use `$product->product_id` this is the way to address objects while your `$product` is an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="cadeau_bewerken">
        <?php if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] ==  $product["user_id"]): ?>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"> Cadeau bewerken </a>
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

In condition you use `$product["user_id"]` as an array, but in link, as an object.
The error says, that it can't get `product_id` property from your variable. I assume, that you should use `$product['product_id']`instead of `$product->product_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$product` variable is array not object so you need to chnage your code as below:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product['product_id]; ?>"> Cadeau bewerken </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your $product variable is not an object. You can check with this

```
var_dump($product)
```

and this should work

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"> Cadeau bewerken </a>
```